# Inner join on an inner join - the column was specified multiple times

Tags: sql, database, debugging, join, inner-join

I have tables like below:
[image]

Where the tables in order are "student", 'course', and 'takes'

I'm having a bit of trouble using joins to collect data. I'm trying to find the names of students who have taken at least one Comp. Sci. course.

This is my query:

```
SELECT S.name
FROM student S
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM takes INNER JOIN course) AS C 
ON S.ID = C.ID AND C.dept_name= 'Comp. Sci.'
```

However, I'm getting an error when I execute:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Also, there's a red underline by "AS C" that says:

```
The column 'course_id' was specified multiple times for 'C'
```

We're not supposed to use natural join, since weve only learnt the basic ones like inner, outer, right, left, cross, etc.

Could someone please help me figure out why Im getting these errors, and debug?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. Chop out code that leaves the error. Read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: What is your DBMS? INNER JOIN without ON is not standard SQL. Always read the manual re functionality you are using. When you posted this were you not told to not use a bare "sql" tag? PS You expect C to be an inner join of takes & course. You don't give a [mre] but presumably they both have a course_id. So why are you surprised a message tells you C has 2 course_id columns? Except you should get that from code that you didn't actually give us. Yet again--[mre]. Find out how inner join works.  And what did you learn researching the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your `inner join` is incorrect, read more about join [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). try the following.

```
SELECT 
   s.name,
   t.*
FROM student s
INNER JOIN takes t 
on s.id = t.id
INNER JOIN course c 
ON t.course_id = c.course_id
WHERE c.dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists` if you just wan the students:

```
select s.*
from students s
where exists (select 1
              from takes t join
                   course c
                   on t.course_id = c.course_id
              where t.id = s.id and t.dept_name = 'Comp Sci.'
             );
```

With `exists`, you don't need to worry about duplicates.